# Internet Explorer stretches image in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create full height section with 2 sections.

In the first one is just text and in the second one a image.

I'm using flexbox for this and it works fine in Chrome, FF, Edge but not in IE.

```css
#super {
  height: 100vh;
}

#super #el-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#super #el-1 .above,
#super #el-1 .below {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#super #el-1 .above {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

#super #el-1 .below img {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="super">

  <div id="el-1">

    <div class="above">
      <h1>Some crazy text here!!!</h1>
      <h2>Wow a second line - amazing :o</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="below">
      <img src="http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0cw3epzv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is notorious for having many [**flexbugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs). It's reliable for very simple flex layouts. But with even the slightest bit of complexity, IE requires "special attention" (i.e., ugly hacks).

In this particular case, it appears IE requires a height limitation on the parent of the image:

Instead of this:

```
.below { }

img {
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Try this:

```
.below {
    flex: 0 0 200px; /* flex-basis: 200px (demo value only) */
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    /* flex: 0 0 100%;  <--- this should work also, but it doesn't */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0cw3epzv/5/)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that for browser compatibility you can try this option. What i did was to remove flex from the ".below" class and centered the img element in it. Hope it helps

```
#super {

  height: 100vh;

  #el-1 {

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;

    .above {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .below {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .above {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 100px 0;
    }

    .below {

      img {
        width: 60%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

    }

  }

}
```